# Using dispatch_once in method swizzling

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime, method-swizzling

In NSHipter's article on [method swizzling](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/), it says "Swizzling should always be done in a dispatch_once."  Why is this necessary since +load happens only once per class?

Comment: Great question.  Not explained in the article and feels like overkill.  +(void)load should only run once.  I can't find any resources that have a counter example.

Comment: I think it is explained, however: *Again, because swizzling changes global state, we need to take every precaution available to us in the runtime. Atomicity is one such precaution, as is a guarantee that code will be executed exactly once, even across different threads*. It's another precautionary step to prevent race conditions since I guess `load` method doesn't necessarily guarantee atomicity but using `dispatch_once` does

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not required. `+load` is guaranteed to be thread-safe and reentrant. See `load_images` in [`objc-runtime-new.mm`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-646/runtime/objc-runtime-new.mm):

```
/***********************************************************************
* load_images
* Process +load in the given images which are being mapped in by dyld.
* Calls ABI-agnostic code after taking ABI-specific locks.
*
* Locking: write-locks runtimeLock and loadMethodLock
**********************************************************************/
const char *
load_images(enum dyld_image_states state, uint32_t infoCount,
            const struct dyld_image_info infoList[])
{
    BOOL found;

    recursive_mutex_lock(&loadMethodLock);

    // Discover load methods
    rwlock_write(&runtimeLock);
    found = load_images_nolock(state, infoCount, infoList);
    rwlock_unlock_write(&runtimeLock);

    // Call +load methods (without runtimeLock - re-entrant)
    if (found) {
        call_load_methods();
    }

    recursive_mutex_unlock(&loadMethodLock);

    return nil;
}
```

Notice the recursive mutex, that guarantees that all loads are done while blocking, and `call_load_methods()` will ensure that +load only gets invoked once per implementation of `+load`.

Note that `+load` is special in that there can be multiple implementations of it on a per-class basis, which is one of the reasons why it's preferred for swizzling - your `+load`, as well as the original `+load` is guaranteed to be called.

Bonus: Here's the relevant documentation on `call_load_methods()` that directly addresses why this is thread safe in the way that it is:

```
/***********************************************************************
* call_load_methods
* Call all pending class and category +load methods.
* Class +load methods are called superclass-first. 
* Category +load methods are not called until after the parent class's +load.
* 
* This method must be RE-ENTRANT, because a +load could trigger 
* more image mapping. In addition, the superclass-first ordering 
* must be preserved in the face of re-entrant calls. Therefore, 
* only the OUTERMOST call of this function will do anything, and 
* that call will handle all loadable classes, even those generated 
* while it was running.
*
* The sequence below preserves +load ordering in the face of 
* image loading during a +load, and make sure that no 
* +load method is forgotten because it was added during 
* a +load call.
* Sequence:
* 1. Repeatedly call class +loads until there aren't any more
* 2. Call category +loads ONCE.
* 3. Run more +loads if:
*    (a) there are more classes to load, OR
*    (b) there are some potential category +loads that have 
*        still never been attempted.
* Category +loads are only run once to ensure "parent class first" 
* ordering, even if a category +load triggers a new loadable class 
* and a new loadable category attached to that class. 
*
* Locking: loadMethodLock must be held by the caller 
*   All other locks must not be held.
**********************************************************************/
void call_load_methods(void)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that article is **suggesting** that "Swizzling should be done in +load". But still you can do swizzling somewhere else.  In this situation you should do swizzling in a dispatch_once for atomicity. I think it's unnecessary to wrap swizzling in a dispatch_once in +load, too.